# how to remove and edit button of telegram bot?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

how to remove or edit buttons of keyboards?

first i create keboard:

```html
<?


$keyboard = [
            'keyboard' => [[['text' => 'a',]],[['text'=>'b' ]]],

 ];

$reply = json_encode($keyboard);

$url1 = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendmessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($text)."&reply_markup=".$reply;
$result1=file_get_contents($url1);



?>
```

created keyboard truely.

but when i try to use api bot to remove not working:

```html
<?

$url1 = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendmessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chat_id."&reply_markup=KeyboardRemove";
$result1=file_get_contents($url1);


?>
```

where is my wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to send **JSON format**, not text, just like [this payload](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?sendMessage-18735e47).

```
{
    "remove_keyboard": true
}
```

Comment: i use $ar1=["remove_keyboard" => true];
$js1=json_encode($ar1);